# MariaDB: how to update column based on modification of another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

original question: Create a way to update a staff member's password when their username is modified. Assume the staff member's password should be the result of the expression

I have staff table that has a Trigger. the Trigger will update staff.password every time the staff.username is modified. but so far no success

[image]

Comment: That doesn't bear much resemblance to trigger or update syntax and should be a before trigger. You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger - and I would avoid using the wizard given that answers will likely be text based to make them generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
if(old.username != new.username)
    THEN UPDATE staff.password
    set new.password = MD5(new.username);
    
    end if;




END
```